# Angular 4 remove required validator conditionally

Tags: forms, angular, validation, typescript

In Angular 4 app I have a form model like this:

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
    title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
});
```

Now what I want is to remove dynamically only the required validator from the control validators array. Something like this:

```
saveDraft() {
    this.form.controls['title'].removeValidator('required'); //Just a fake implementation for demonstration
}
```

This question is not the duplicate of the mentioned question. My case is different I just want to remove the required validator unknowingly the other ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 conditional Validators.required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118721/angular-2-conditional-validators-required)

Answer (score 136):

if you want to add validation try this one.

```
saveDraft() {
   this.form.get('title').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
   this.form.get('title').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

if you want to remove validators try this one.

```
saveDraft() {
 this.form.get('title').clearValidators();
 this.form.get('title').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In my case I have dropdown on change event I am calling a function a condition to set the validators as above. Any suggestions what might be wrong.

Comment: @Zaker Please post a new question, with your code, and link to this question.

Comment: for anyone else running into this issue, I had to do a this.form.get('title').setValidators(null); this.form.get('title').setErrors(null) in order to ensure this.form.valid = true

Comment: @CalebSwank Thanks for adding this. `setErrors(null)` and `setValidators(null);` works charmingly.  :-)

Comment: But after removing errros when you add required validator again, you need add errors :(.

Answer (score 8):

I don't like clearing and setting validators, as I have to repeat all static validators (patterns, min, max, etc.) just to have a dynamic "required" validator.

I use a conditional validator:

```
export function conditionalValidator(condFn: (control: AbstractControl) => boolean,
validators: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (control) => {
    if (!condFn(control)) {
      return null;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(validators)) {
      return validators(control);
    }

    return validators.map(v => v(control)).reduce((errors, result) =>
      result === null ? errors :
        (Object.assign(errors || {}, result))
    );
  };
}
```

I can then mix a static validator with a dynamic "required" condition:

```
this.fb.group({name: ['', [Validators.minLength(4),
                 conditionalValidator(this.isClientProj, Validators.required)]]}
```

Where `isClientProj()` is the condition function (closure)

Comment: I think something to note here is that something needs to be done to insure that a change in the condition value triggers revalidation. I don't think a change in a checkbox will trigger validation on other form fields.

Comment: Right, and this is the problem I am currently trying to solve. If you're in an invalid state and the validator condition changes to false, then the form is still invalid unless you manually kick off a validation cycle which is less than desirable. The Validator interface does define a changed event hook which as far as I can tell is what Angular hooks into to trigger validation again, so I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 6):

we can use `setValidators` to remove validation.

```js
setValidators(newValidator: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]): void
```

### setValidators() - setValidators programmatically adds the sync validators. This method will remove all the previously added sync or async validators.

```js
this.form.get('title').setValidators(null); 
this.form.get('title').setErrors(null);
```

Comment: It work for me. It make the form valid when the value of the item is null.

Answer (score 6):

You can use: AbstractControl.removeValidators(validator: ValidatorFn)

Not sure if it is possible in angular 4, but definately in Angular 12 and higher.

It needs however, a reference to the [exact same function](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#removevalidators).
Just giving it Validators.required does not work. You need to create a unique reference to it:

```
requiredValidator = Validators.required;
   
this.form = this._fb.group({
    title: ['', [this.requiredValidator, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    description: ['', [this.requiredValidator, Validators.minLength(3)]]
}); 

saveDraft() {
    this.title.removeValidators(this.requiredValidator); 
}

get title(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.get('title');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To Add Validators:

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
    title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
});
```

or

`this.form.get('title').setValidators([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3),
                                       Validators.maxLength(50)]);`

To Remove the 'Required' validator only, you can reset the validators.

```
saveDraft() {
     this.form.get('title').setValidators([Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]);
     this.form.get('title').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

**updateValueAndValidity** determines how the control propagates changes and emits events when the value and validators are changed

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Angular doesn't have a removeValidator capability at this point in time.  All you can do is re-set the validators without the one you want to remove, so you need to know which validators you want to keep rather than which one you want to remove. so this:

```
this.form.get('title').setValidators([Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]);
```

Is the closest you have to a remove function.  You can't access the current validators on a formcontrol either to try and write your own remove function.  The best you could do is write your own form control validation manager class that can keep track of the validators on a given control and manage them for you.

Comment: I'm here because my control with min/maxlength set still gets `required` error on an empty field.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with saving entry as draft and prepared the following solution:

```
@Component({
    // ...
})
export class FormComponent{
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)],
            description: ['', Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)],
            address: this.fb.group({
                line1: ['', Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)],
                line2: ['', Validators.maxLength(100)]
            })
        });
    }    

    validateDraft(formElement: FormGroup | FormArray | FormControl): boolean {
        let result = true;

        Object.keys(formElement.controls).forEach(field => {
            const control = formElement.get(field);

            if(control instanceof FormControl) {
                control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });

                if(control.errors && control.errors['required']) {
                    control.markAsUntouched({ onlySelf: true });
                }
                else if(control.invalid) {
                    result = false;
                }
            } else if (control instanceof FormArray) {
                if (!this.validateDraft(control)) {
                    result = false;
                } 
            }else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
                if (!this.validateDraft(control)) {
                    result = false;
                }   
            }
        });
    }

    saveDraft(){
        if(this.validateDraft(this.form)){
            //save draft - ignore required errors
        }
    }

    save(){
        if(this.form.valid){
            //save
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best solution for me

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to clear validation from reactive form

```
this.form.controls['title'].clearValidators();
this.form.controls['title'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

you can use this to add validation in reactive form

```
this.form.controls['title'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
this.form.controls['title'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.fromName.get("formControlName").setValidators([Validators.required]);//setting validation
this.fromName.get("formControlName").setErrors({'required':true});//error message
this.fromName.updateValueAndValidity();//update validation


this.fromName.get("formControlName").clearValidators([Validators.required]);//clear validation
this.fromName.get("formControlName").setErrors(null);//updating error message
this.fromName.updateValueAndValidity();//update validation
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: clearValidators() doesn't accept arguments, and clears all validators.
See https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#clearValidators

Comment: There are no parameters on ```clearValidators()```  . Why people up vote this wrong info..!!!

Comment: clearValidators() is supposed to clear the entire list of validators, you can't choose and tell what specific validators you want to remove in clearValidators()

Answer (score 0):

Use empty array to remove all existing validators.

```
this.frmFeasibility.controls['pop_name'].setValidators([]);
this.frmFeasibility.controls['pop_name'].updateValueAndValidity();
```