# Angular Remove a Specific Form Validator, Not All of them in Formbuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

In Angular Formbuilder, how do I remove a Specific Validator?
There is

```
this.form.get('lastName').clearValidators()
```

However, this removes ALL validators, just want to remove the 'Required' validators, and keep min and max length.

```
this.editAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'firstName': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'lastName': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'city': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'zipCode': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]]
})
```

**Resource:**

[Angular 4 remove required validator conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488078/angular-4-remove-required-validator-conditionally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built-in way to achieve this.

However, you can follow this approach:

```js
const validators = [Validators.required, Validators.min(30), Validators.max(100)];
const fc = new FormControl('', validators)

console.log(fc.valid) // false

const newValidators = validators.filter(v => v !== Validators.required);

fc.setValidators(newValidators);
fc.updateValueAndValidity();

console.log(fc.valid) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
this.form.get('lastName').setValidators([Validators.maxLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]);
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: welI have array of validators, so want solution which is reproducible and can be used in multiple situations