# How to remove the required validators from Angular input?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Have been using Angular 13 in my application and have a scenario where I have to remove a required field validation on value changes. Find this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-13-starter-x1xj4z-ibnbmu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo of what I am trying to achieve.

In the demo atleast one field is required. If I add firstname, validation on nickname should be removed or vice versa.

Have tried using the updateValueandValidity method but that doesn't seem to work as well. If I do not pass any opts on the updateValueandValidity method, Maximum Call stack error appears as valuechanges is called infinitely. Below is code from stackblitz.

HTML:

```
   <h1>Mandatory to add atleast one name</h1>
   <form [formGroup]="registerForm">
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="firstName" />
        </mat-form-field>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
       <mat-form-field>
         <mat-label>Nick Name</mat-label>
         <input matInput formControlName="nickName" />
       </mat-form-field>
     </div>
  </form>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public registerForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
       nickName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
    this.toggleRequiredValidationOnInput();
  }
  toggleRequiredValidationOnInput() {
    Object.keys(this.registerForm.controls).forEach((field)=>{
     this.registerForm.get(field)?.valueChanges.subscribe(()=> {
       let isMandatory = false;
       isMandatory = !Object.keys(this.registerForm.controls).some((field) => {
       return this.registerForm.get(field)?.value;
     });
     this.updateFieldWithMandatoryCheck(isMandatory);
   });
 });
}
updateFieldWithMandatoryCheck(isMandatory) {
  Object.keys(this.registerForm.controls).forEach((field) => {
    if (isMandatory) { this.registerForm.get(field).addValidators(Validators.required);
  } else {
    this.registerForm.get(field).removeValidators(Validators.required);
  }
  this.registerForm
    .get(field)
    .updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: It had been discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488078/angular-4-remove-required-validator-conditionally

Comment: @MissaConstantPierrehardwork the issue is both fields are interdependent and changes in one emit changes in the other and back and forth which is causing stack overflow error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did. The trick to breaking the loop was using the `distinctUntilChanged` pipe. See the demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-13-starter-x1xj4z-3mt8qy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      nickName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });

    this.registerForm
      .get('firstName')
      .valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe({
        next: (val) => {
          if (val) {
            this.registerForm.get('nickName').clearValidators();
            this.registerForm.get('nickName').updateValueAndValidity();
          } else {
            this.registerForm
              .get('nickName')
              .setValidators([Validators.required]);
            this.registerForm.get('nickName').updateValueAndValidity();
          }
        },
      });

    this.registerForm
      .get('nickName')
      .valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe({
        next: (val) => {
          if (val) {
            this.registerForm.get('firstName').clearValidators();
            this.registerForm.get('firstName').updateValueAndValidity();
          } else {
            this.registerForm
              .get('firstName')
              .setValidators([Validators.required]);

            this.registerForm.get('firstName').updateValueAndValidity();
          }
        },
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding/removing the validators manually, you could put a custom cross-field-validator function onto the `FormGroup`, like this:

```
private checkAtLeastOneRequired(form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors {
    const ffFirstName: AbstractControl = form.get('firstName');
    const ffNickName: AbstractControl = form.get('nickName');

    let errors: ValidationErrors = null;
    if (!ffFirstName.value && !ffNickName.value) {
        errors = { atLeastOneRequired: true };
    }

    ffFirstName.setErrors(errors);
    ffNickName.setErrors(errors);

    return errors;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerForm = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl(''),
       nickName: new FormControl(''),
    }, this.checkAtLeastOneRequired);
}
```